# Angular js timeout inside link function after dom manipulation

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive, through which I am dynamically adding span before a label in html. The span tag is created using template property. Now I have one case where label is displayed none so no need for span to add.

Can we use timeout inside link function after DOM manipulation is completed in link function? Since i am able to get instance of all label elements after DOM has completed loading. Below is the directive code working as expected.

```
myModule.directive('lockIcon', ['$compile', '$filter', '$timeout', function($compile, $filter, $timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
         visible: '=visible'
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
        var template = '<span ng-hide="visible" class="tif-lock lock-noneditable-indication" title="'+$filter('transcribe')('tooltip non editable indication text')+'"></span>';
        var newElement = angular.element(template);
        element.wrap( '<div class="lock-icon-wrapper"></div>' ).parent().append(newElement);
        $compile(newElement)(scope);
        $timeout(function() {
            var lockLabelElm = angular.element('.lock-icon-wrapper label');
            if(lockLabelElm) {
                angular.forEach(lockLabelElm, function(elmlock) {
                    var labelDisplayState = angular.element(elmlock).css('display');
                    if(labelDisplayState === 'none') {
                        angular.element(elmlock).next().css('display','none');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble determining what you are asking. It sounds like the code example is 'working as expected', so what would you like to see happen that's not happening?

Comment: I want to confirm whether it is best practice to use timeout in link function for dom manipulation or is there any other way.